# generate non duplicate integers in Lua

Tags: random, lua, unique

I am trying to generate 5 random non duplicate values between 0,500 and assign them to 5 variables using Lua.

So far I have used the following code which unsuccessfully attempts to generate the random numbers and assigns the values. The problem is:

1. this code is sometime generating the duplicate numbers
2. the name which I want to look like x-1, x-2 and so on, prints like x-1, x-12.

Can you please help me with this.

Example:

```
v_Name = "x-"
for i =1, 5 do
  X = math.random (0, 500)
  v_Name = v_Name..(i)
  print (v_Name)
  print (X)
 end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution, clarified in the comments:

```
math.randomseed( os.time() ) -- first, sets a seed for the pseudo-random generator

local  function my_random (t,from, to)  -- second, exclude duplicates
   local num = math.random (from, to)
   if t[num] then  num = my_random (t, from, to)   end
   t[num]=num 
   return num
end

local t = {}    -- initialize  table with not duplicate values
local v_Name = "x-"
for i =1, 5 do
  X = my_random (t, 0, 500)
  v_Name = v_Name .. i    -- It is better to use the table here and concatenate it after..
  print (v_Name, "=" ,X)
 end
```

Comment: `t` will overflow if the loop count is greater then the range of random numbers. but that's not intended here. you cannot generate 501 random numbers between [0-500] ;) but a check for this should be in place. I will add this in my utilities, thank you

Comment: Interesting example of abusing recursion for the sake of avoiding loops :-)

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach for this sort of thing is to do a random shuffle of an array containing all your possible random numbers and take the first `n` of those. As an optimization you can only shuffle the first `n` elements you need.

```
local meta = {
  __index = function( _, i ) return i end
}

local function random_n( n, i, j )
  local result = {}
  local temp = setmetatable( {}, meta )
  for k = 1, n do
    -- swap first element in range with randomly selected element in range
    local idx = math.random( i, j )
    local v = temp[ idx ]
    temp[ idx ] = temp[ i ]
    result[ k ] = v
    i = i + 1 -- first element in range is fixed from now on
  end
  return result
end

math.randomseed( os.time() )

local t = random_n( 5, 0, 500 )
for i,v in ipairs( t ) do
  print( i, v )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple answer without metatables..

```
local result = {}
local rand_num = {}
local v_Name = "x-"

for i=1, 500, 1 do
table.insert(rand_num, i)
end

for i=1, 5, 1 do
local r = math.random(1, #rand_num)
table.insert(result, rand_num[r])
table.remove(rand_num, r)
end

for i,v in pairs(result) do
print(v_Name .. v)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I’m new in Lua
> Here is my attempt that is giving the solution properly without using the math.random function. Do we really have to use the function by the way

```
local count = 0
local v_name =“ “

for count = 1, 10 do
    v_name = v_name.. “x- “ .. count..” “
end
print (v_name)
```

Comment: The question asks for a series of *random* numbers. This answer does not provide that.